# Is there a way to avoid header files completely?

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to know if there's a way of declaring a ref class in a cpp file and then reference it in another ref class in another cpp file. both ref classes would be in the same namespace. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
//class1.cpp

namespace nm
{
    public ref class class1
    {

    };
}

//class2.cpp
namespace nm
{
    public ref class class2
    {
    private:
        class1^ _member;
    };
}
```

I get 2 strange errors from the compiler and one a bit clearer from Intellisense:

1. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
2. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
       does not support default-int
3. IntelliSense: identifier "class1" is undefined

If I use header files all this goes away. Is there a way to make it work without the need for header files? Do I need a smarter compiler?

Comment: Is there any very good reason not to use header files?

Comment: @ Nidhoegger Not really, it's just that I'm learning and I would like to focus on the language and leave this type of things like linking and whatnot for latter.

Comment: @Nidhoegger sorry to insist, and thanks for your help. So I assume there's no way of avoiding the header files, or at least none that a good programmer would recommend? I just want to make it clear

Comment: If you absolutely hate header files, there are CLI languages that don't use them, such as C#.

Comment: If you dont want headerfiles put alle classes, etc in one file together with the main. But thats very very ugly code then. Or plainly use Java, C#, Delphi, etc, which put definition and implementation in one file.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen thanks, I'll take a look
Nidhoegger I agree, that would be worse than header files.

OK, I'll keep using header files while studying C++. Thanks.

Comment: Header files are a fundamental part of C++. You could avoid them, but you'll end up missing an important part of the language. Also, if you're just learning, you may want to focus on just C++, not C++/CLI. C++/CLI is intended as a bridge between .Net and unmanaged C++. C++/CLI has all the complexities of C++, all the complexities of C#, and a few more of its own thrown it. For a primary development language, I'd recommend you go either C++ or C#, not the middle ground.

Comment: You can forward-declare a class by writing `ref class class1;` above the definition of `class2`, inside the namespace block. But, like others have said, you definitely should not try to circumvent header files.

Comment: Completely agree with @DavidYaw. C++/CLI exists for a very specific niche purpose, and for primary development either real C++ (for native code) or C# (for managed code) is a better choice.

Comment: @ David Yaw I will finish my current study and then I'll consider what to do. I've been told that to actually write working software is a lot harder in C++ because of the lack of .NET class library. But I heard C# lacks big things like a way to code for DirectX, and then I kind of settled for C++/CLI hoping it would give me the best of both. Now I'm not so sure.

Comment: C++/CLI does give you the capability to do both, but that means it's also the most compex. If you're looking to program games specifically, I recommend you learn C++. Anything else, and I'd learn C# first. Once you know *both* C# and C++, then turn toward C++/CLI to link the two.

Comment: C# definitely can do DirectX, but as it's a managed language, you'd have to account for GC lags which you definitely don't want in a game, and you'd have to write code in an alloc-free way, which... basically makes you write code similar to what you'd write in C. In this case C++/CLI gets you the worst of both worlds (GC + thunking + less friendly than C#).